# Racy and lewd Sci-Fi comic from late 1990's/early 2000's with two girls, fighting?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember this comic book from around 2000's. I was too young to actually read it but stared at the cover very often. I don't think this was a series but perhaps a pilot of some sort.

The cover had these two girls in it, a blonde and a brunette, from a backward angle. They were riding a speeder, rocket or something like that. The other one was steering and holding her butt up. And the other one was sitting down with this great smoking gun on her shoulder. They were wearing skimpy outfits that had this metallic looking glossy texture and the shape reminded me of one-piece swimsuits, just with lots of holes

I also think that on the flip side of the comic book, there was a different story with the same characters, but drawn in a 'manga-ish' style. But I don't think the comic itself was Japanese, the other half had very western looking. Only once I saw a glimpse of the contents and it looked kind of violent, with blood and everything.

And I don't think this was like an erotica or anything like that. It was sold in regular shops. I once remember reading a Spawn comic that was on the shelf next to this one, in our local super market.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: My first impulse is "Dirty Pair", but that's the wrong art style and the wrong hair colors.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Well, that was quick. Apparently I misremembered the hair color. https://www.darkhorse.com/Comics/99-383/The-Dirty-Pair-Run-from-the-Future-1-of-4-Hughes-cover

Comment: @FuzzyBoots What's the procedure here? Wanna post this as and answer?

Comment: @Rum Rums: Would you like to post it as an answer? You do get credit for that.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Ah, okay.

Comment: :) Ideally, give the name of the work, link to a place that describes it well (and hopefully matches your question) and quote a decent excerpt, then add an image such as the one you found.

Comment: You won't be able to accept it for 48 hours after you asked the question, but after that, please do accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Oh, already added the answer. Feel free to take the information from there and make it more comprehensive and I'll like it :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The cover I remembered was from Adam Warren's ["The Dirty Pair Run From The Future"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dirty_Pair) #1(of 4).

[image: Cover]
<sub>[*Source*](https://www.darkhorse.com/Comics/99-383/The-Dirty-Pair-Run-from-the-Future-1-of-4-Hughes-cover)</sub>

So apparently I misremembered a lot of things. The hair colours were wrong for one. Secondly I wasn't aware that this was an "English-language manga"-comic, (don't really know how that works) based on the Japanese light novels, manga, anime etc: [“Dirty Pair”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Pair).

Thank you, @FuzzyBoots for setting me on the right trail.